# Azure DevOps Rest API env select

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I do have a pretty simple script for calling Azure DevOps rest API to run pipeline.

```
$pushFileJSON =' 
{ 
    "stagesToSkip": [], 
    "resources": { 
        "repositories": { 
            "self": { 
                "refName": "develop" 
            } 
        } 
    }, 
    "templateParameters": {}, 
    "variables": {} 
} 
' 
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/pipelines/$id/runs?api-version=5.1-preview.1" 
Write-Host "Trigger pipline: $url" 
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method 'POST' -ContentType "application/json" -Body $pushFileJSON -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
```

Script works fine and triggers default env (DEV).
But I have a different envs (DEV,QA,PROD).
How to specify env in Rest API Call to run pipeline for QA/PROD ?
Thank you!

Comment: How do you trigger those envs not with api?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty easy.
Need to use section:
"templateParameters": {
"env":"value"
}